# Mayfly identification - Oregon

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found in a web by a very small, slow moving stream. Douglas-fir forest in Gales Creek area, April 28.

[image]

Comment: Great picture -- it's reaching for the sky!

Comment: Approximate size?